# Live-Usb: udev requires hotplug support not started

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, udev, live-usb

I tried to run kali from USB on my laptop, I clicked run from USB. At the kali menu -> Kali live.

Then the system started to load things allot of Lines..

Then an Error occurred:

> "udev requires hotplug support not started. ... failed! failed!"

and its continued to load things (its didnt get to the green [ok]-s)

https://i.imgsafe.org/9574f7f57b.jpg

And then it's throw me to terminal tty1 and ask for login, I couldnt login..(I tried root-toor, and also root-root noting worked)

> "progress linux 1.9 localhost.localdomain tty1"

https://i.imgsafe.org/9574d2822a.jpg

Necessary details:

- Kali version kali-linux-2016.2-amd64
- Kali installation USB-live
- Specific hardware models you are having trouble with HP ay-101nj:

  1. Intel® Core™ i5-7200U Processor
  2. 8 GB ram - ddr4
  3. SSD 256GB
  4. AMD Radeon™ R5 M430
  5. Bios InsydeH2O F.23
  6. OS windows 10. The Laptop came with FreeDOS2.0

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27412488/5848185

Comment: didnt worked @GAD3R

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem with my hp. try to download the newest weekly release of kali. http://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/ it helped me.